# Textarea did not focus but submit instead

Tags: javascript, html, forms, focus, textarea

I have a textarea which catch the keyphrase of characters' count. I also have a javascript codes in mine which return false if the textarea have no character typed in the field at all or at least 20 chars. This is my scripts:

**Javascript**

```
        function CheckLength() {
            var msg_area = document.getElementById("error2");
            msg_area.innerHTML = "";
            if (document.getElementById("staf_address").value.length < 20) {
                document.getElementById("error1").className = "par control-group error";
                document.getElementById("staf_address").focus();​
                msg_area.innerHTML = "YOU DID NOT ENTER ENOUGH INFORMATION";
                return false;
            } else document.getElementById("addstaf").submit();
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="stdform stdform2" method="post" id="addstaf" action="index.php?site=addstafrev" onsubmit="return CheckLength()" />
    <div id="error1">
    <label for="staf_address">Address</label>
        <span class="field">
        <textarea cols="80" rows="5" name="staf_address" id="staf_address" class="span5 textarea2" maxlength="120" required /></textarea>
        <span class="help-inline" id="error2"></span>
        </span>
    </div><!--par-->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
</form>
```

There is no problem at all, at the beginning. The textarea will be not submitted if the characters in `id=staf_address` are less than 20 chars. The error will be displayed on `id=error2`. So, the textarea and the form work fine, no problem. The thing is that, it doesn't focus on text area during the form is submitted (if the textarea is less than 20 chars). So, I add a line of codes that is this line:

```
document.getElementById("staf_address").focus();​
```

After that, here comes the problem. The document won't check my javascript instead it submit the form eventhough the textarea only have 1 char. How to solve this?

Need just a plain javascript only.

Comment: check any js error found in console, i could see some error in console. pleasecheck

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil what console? I don't have any 'console' to check the error. So far as I see, the codes are fine. Can you tell me the error?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/k0LLjfxj/

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil what exactly did you change in that code? I don't see any difference with mine. Can you tell me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I pasted your code into JS Fiddle I noticed a weird character after focus();

[image]

Deleting it seems to fix the problem.

preventDefault() is an event method so it can only be used if an event object is passed into the function. Ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Comment: Wow, the heck is that? Anyway, that really solve my problem! Maybe I got this weird character because I copy from other codes.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the button, your form is submitted. You need to prevent this with `preventDefault()` which will stop the submission, allowing you to perform functions and whatnot before manually submitting upon the proper submission.

Remember, a `button` inside a form tag defaults to a submit button!

Comment: But, without `preventDefault()` previously, my form work fine. It didn't submit at all and the error displayed that I don't have enough chars. Just when I add the focus line, the script failed to run.